# Basic PHP logic problem

Tags: php, logic

```
$this->totplpremium is 2400
$this->minpremiumq is 800
```

So why would this ever return true?!

```
if ($this->totplpremium < $this->minpremiumq){
```

The figures are definitely correct and I am definitely using the 'less than' symbol. I can't work it out.

Comment: Can you show a full working code example?

Comment: Try adding debug output (even just a simple set of echo lines) to be sure that the two variables are 2400 and 800, and if they are, I'd look at your curly braces and see if any are out of place.

Comment: There is an error in the values i guess. Use `var_dump($this)` and post the output please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe there's some kind of conversion problem. Try use

```
var_dump($this->totplpremium);
var_dump($this->minpremiumq);
if ($this->totplpremium < $this->minpremiumq){
  ...
}
```

to see if the datatypes are allright

EDIT: There are tools that enables you to debug your code more easily than using debugging outputs - http://xdebug.org/ (an extension for PHP that enables you debugging) and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPEd (It's commercial. I don't know if there's an alternative.)

Comment: Could be strings with whitespace. `2400 > 800`, `"2400" > "800"`, but `"2400 " < "800 "` - they won't get type-juggled to int because of the spaces, and lexicographically 2400 is smaller.

Comment: 2400 *IS* less than 800 when compared as strings.

Comment: @Salman A: not it isn't. From the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php): *If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number  and the comparison performed numerically.*

Comment: @MartyIX: Xdebug + Notepad++ + Xdebug helper for Firefox is a lightweight opensource debugging environment. All the big IDEs like Eclipse support Xdebug too, of course.

Comment: @Tgr: very true but, as you mentioned above, its possible to confuse php into using string comparison for numbers.

Comment: That's solved it - $this->totplpremium was a string. I had previously used "number_format()" on it.

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping the 'numbers' with intval:

```
if (intval($this->totplpremium) < intval($this->minpremiumq)){
//...
}
```

If this works as expected then you really need to check what types totplpremium and minpremiumq are by using gettype, for example:

```
print(gettype($this->totplpremium));
print(gettype($this->minpremiumq));
```

With that info you should be able to pinpoint your error.

Answer (score 0):

As an alphabetical comparison, the following statement is true:

```
"800" > "2400"
```

(because 8 is greater than 2)

Comment: It is false, actually. PHP type-juggles string containing pure numbers into numbers before doing the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$totplpremium="2400 ";
$minpremiumq="800";

var_dump(($totplpremium < $minpremiumq)?true:false);
var_dump(((int)$totplpremium < (int)$minpremiumq)?true:false);

?>
```

I'd guess you should either double check where these values come from OR make sure they are integers.

Good luck coding!

Comment: Yes, the space after 2400 is there for a purpose: forcing them to be compared as strings!